# Proper database indexes with subquery

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

**THE INFO**

Currently I have two tables I am working with- a POST table that holds data for a individual posts, and a FAVORITES table that holds data for users that opt to save favorite posts in their profile.

The tables look like this:

[image: POSTS and FAVORITES table]

On the POSTS table there is only a primary key on id, no indexes that I have set. On Favorites I have a combined index that I was testing of (postid, deviceid).

The POSTS table contains approx. 10,000 entries.

The FAVORITES table contains approx. 4,680,500 entries.

The query I use to grab the favorites from a particular deviceid is:

```
SELECT post FROM POSTS 
WHERE id IN 
   (SELECT postid FROM favourites WHERE deviceid="12d4a4a4a4a4a4a");
```

**THE PROBLEM:**

With the amount of data being returned, and several devices having multiple favorites, the query can take upwards of 7-10 seconds to both COUNT favorites for a particular device and/or SELECT using the above query and subquery. When this happens during peak times, you can obviously imagine the issues that can cause.

Caching the query results is an option, but since the data is pretty specific in that the same user is not calling the query multiple times, but rather unique instances, I think there is a better solution.  On another note, caching would need to be short lived, which would nullify its benefit.

I know the method of indexing, and I am familiar with foreign keys, but I'm not sure practically if and how they could be implemented between the query and the subquery to enhance performance.

Any advice/guidance is much appreciated.

Cheers,

Jared

Comment: The quiry performance may be analysed with help of execution plan. May you post for yours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT post FROM POSTS 
INNER JOIN favourites ON POSTS.id=favourites.postid 
WHERE favourites.deviceid="12d4a4a4a4a4a4a");
```

split the index in `favourites` in 2 indices one on `deviceid` and one on `postid`

Comment: this did the trick, altering the query and redoing the indexes, as others suggested, has solved the issue. thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Why use a subquery? Have you tried a join?

```
SELECT post FROM posts INNER JOIN favourites ON posts.id=favourites.postid WHERE deviceid="12d4a4a4a4a4a4a"
```

You won't be using (only) your indices to retrieve the query results since the `post` field is not in any index. So you might actually end up saving time by making one query to get all the matching IDs from `posts`, then a second to get the `post` values.

Using `EXPLAIN SELECT...` will also help you optimize this query. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you could do to improve performance:

- Separate the device_id out to a device table with a surrogate primary key (an int) and a non-clustered index on the device_id varchar. The favorites table should only include the device table surrogate key. This should make the favorites table smaller and should make your favorites table index smaller. The smaller the index and smaller the table, the faster it will be to search.
- Your favorites table index is wrong. It should not be (post_id,device_id). It should be (device_id,post_id) as your query needs to search by device_id first. As your favorites table row is so small, I question the value of including the post_id in the index. It just isn't worth the extra space for a possible marginal improvement in query speed.

EDIT: You need the post_id in the index to keep the entries unique (just make sure device_id is first).

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL, composite indexes can only be used in the order the keys are defined. So for index `(postid, deviceid)`, you can only use the index if you have a `postid` and need the `deviceid`. In your query here you're doing the opposite--you have a constant `deviceid` and want corresponding `postid`. So your query is not using any indexes.

[More information on mysql composite indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).

You should either add a `deviceid` index or reverse the index so that it's `(deviceid, postid)`.

By the way, your `favorites` table looks a lot like a junction table. Consider whether you need the `id` column at all.